# Export action group template in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Several action groups (of type `Microsoft.Insights/actionGroups`) should be included in my ARM template. Is there any way of retrieving their ARM specification?

*What I tried* -
I would expect you can use `export template` just like for other resources.
This is however *not* possible from:

- Within the action group,
- `All Resources` - action groups cannot be found there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not quite clear on what is going wrong. I am able to 'Export template' on my Action Groups. I navigate to 'All resources', check the option to 'Show hidden types', and then select my action groups. I can then export the ARM template. I can also navigate to the resource group containing them and export the action groups that way, too. Is there any more information or screen capture you can provide?

Comment: Perfect. The crux was that I wasn't aware that action groups are considered hidden types, I can export the template now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`All Resources` -> Show hidden types -> Select action group -> `export template`